# How should i add this syntax to my html antlr4 grammar?

Tags: html, antlr4, mustache

First of all this is an example of what I'm supposed to do

```
<p cp-for="x in t;i=index"> {{x}}, {{i}} </p>
```

I need to parse the mustache syntax separately from HTML text
(Which means the comma must not be parsed as html text).

And this is part of the grammar i wrote:

```
OPEN_MUSTACHE: '{{' -> pushMode (MUSTACHE_SYNTAX)

mode MUSTACHE_SYNTAX;

//there are other tokens describing the syntax but i didn't write it

CLOSE_MUSTACHE: '}}' -> popMode
```

So if i want to add another mustache tag like in the example, how can i tell the lexer to look ahead and not pop immediately after it sees MUSTACHE_CLOSE?

P.S
this is my first time asking a question on this website;
I apologize if my question is not clear

Edit: i now understand that i got the grammar syntax wrong,
The comma in `{{ x }} , {{ i }}` is actually plain html text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So if i want to add another mustache tag like in the example, how can i tell the lexer to look ahead and not pop immediately after it sees MUSTACHE_CLOSE?

For the input `{{#check}}, {{/check}}`, the lexer should create the following tokens:

- `{{`: open token
- `#`: open tag token
- `check`: name/id token
- `}}`: close token
- `,`: plain HTML token
- : plain HTML token
- `{{`: open token
- `/`: close tag token
- `check`: name/id token
- `}}`: close token

So you can just pop back to the default mode when you encounter `}}` inside your `MUSTACHE_SYNTAX` mode.

And then in your parser, you do something like this:

```
parser grammar MustacheParser;

options {
  tokenVocab=MustacheLexer;
}

template
 : template_contents EOF
 ;

template_contents
 : template_part*
 ;

template_part
 : html
 | mustache
 ;

html
 : HTML+
 ;

mustache
 : section
 | ...
 ;

section
 : '{{' '#' NAME '}}' template_contents '{{' '/' NAME '}}'
 ;
```

(Of course the literal tokens, like `'{{'`, `'#'` etc., are not allowed inside a parser grammar, it's just pseudo code. Replace them with the tokens from your lexer grammar.)